# Is there any way to make natural key as a key of Application context?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data JPA and I have some questions.
My user entity likes below.

```java
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

}
```

Now, in my application, I have findByEmail method.
But when I check my query log, the query send to the database per every findByEmail method call.
How can I make my findByEmail to bring from cache?

### What I tried

- Using natural Key.

```
private final CustomUserRepository userRepository;

@Transactional
@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    userRepository.findByEmail("test");
    userRepository.findByEmail("test");
}
```

If I do as above, log printed like follow

```
select user_.id as id1_0_ from user user_ where user_.email=?
```

I want to use email as a natural key, not a primary key. What should I do?

### repository - now

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

### repository - when using HibernateSession

```
@Repository
public class CustomUserRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public User findByEmail(String email) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        return session.byNaturalId(User.class)
                .using("email", email)
                .load();
    }
}
```

My expectation is to make my JPARepository's findByEmail method to use application context's cache.
Please let me know what to do

Comment: Show me your `userRepository`

Answer (score 0):

For natural id caching to work, you must annotate the entity with `@NaturalIdCache` and enable second level caching. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naturalid-caching) and [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching) for more details.

Comment: Even though I tried it, my JpaRepository still can't use NaturalIdCache...
Is there any other way to avoid injecting EntityManager?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can't use NaturalIdCache", but if all of the above doesn't help you, you will have to create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.